# Spring Batch Using Java No XML 3.0.8.RELEASE

Tags: spring-batch

I would like to pass in a "timestamp" into the JobParameters that gets passed to JobLauncher so I can run a job multiple times a day.

With XML I was able to do this:

`JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder().addLong("time",    System.currentTimeMillis()).toJobParameters();
    JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters);`

Now that I am trying only Java inside Spring Boot framework, I am at a loss.

Startup class with main:

    `@SpringBootApplication
    public class SpringBatchAnnotatedApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBatchAnnotatedApplication.class, args);`

And code eg from class that starts Job:

`@Bean
    public Job testJob(JobCompletionNotificationListener listener) {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("testJob")
                .preventRestart()
                .listener(listener)
                .flow(step1())
                .end()
                .build();
    }`

Advice? I am following docs here using https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.0.x/reference/html/job.html#configureJob [ Java ] Maybe there is a better reference?

Comment: I ended up finding another person who had a issue close to mine and added this to the main method of the SpringBootApplication.    `ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(SpringBatchAnnotatedApplication.class, args);
  JobLauncher jobLauncher = ctx.getBean(JobLauncher.class);
  JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder().addLong("time", System.currentTimeMillis()).toJobParameters();

  jobLauncher.run(ctx.getBean(Job.class), jobParameters);` and it worked, starts up with a custom timestamp each time. Not sure if this is right or wrong. But moving forward.

Comment: Update. When using this in the main, it calls the job two times. So this is not a valid solution. Don't use.

Answer (score 0):

Below should work for you. I am using same configuration and it's working fine for me.

```
JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder()
                                   .addDate("time", new Date())
                                   .toJobParameters();
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring Batch has the concept of a `RunIdIncrementer` for this very use case.  It doesn't pass a timestamp, instead it increments a job parameter.  I'd recommend using this approach instead of manipulating the job parameters.  You can read more about the `RunIdIncrementer` in the documentation here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/launch/support/RunIdIncrementer.html